# Set iOS app visible to selected users on App Store

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I have purchased the **Apple Developer Program** and built an iOS app which works only for iPad.

Now I want to upload the same iOS app on iTunes Connect and will submit it for review, but when my app will go live, I don't want it to be visible for everyone. I want to show my app for some selected users.

I know that the **Apple Developer Enterprise Program** is available for this requirement but I don't want to purchase it.

Secondly, I like to know if it's possible to attach some password to an iOS app before downloading it from the App Store, so that only those users  will download it who have a password.

Comment: i don't think such facilities are available from apple to manage visibility and restrict user from download are available.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently **no option** for this, at least not in the way you want to do it.

You can distribute your app through TestFlight or a third-party ad hoc distribution service. Alternatively, you can implement a password system to your app, so only the selected users can view its content.

Comment: how i can set password in app installation

Answer (score 0):

You can distribute your app through TestFlight. you can use internal and external users. you can input upto 2000 users in external.